# How do i get mail scope permissions for yahoo app?

Tags: permissions, oauth-2.0, yahoo, yahoo-api, yahoo-mail

I need my yahoo app to access user's emails via OAuth2.0 explicit grant flow.

While looking at the document published by yahoo at "https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth2/guide/openid_connect/getting_started.html" and other blog "http://wpweb.co.in/documents/social-network-integration/yahoo/" I can see that it includes the "mail read" scope permission for the yahoo app... but when I tried to create a yahoo app, the "mail" permission section is not even there to begin with...

Please advise... Do I have to buy the Yahoo Premium Mail To get this feature? If so please send the url where I can buy the Yahoo Premium mail service... I couldn't find it anywhere... all I could find is how to remove the ads from the mail service...

Comment: did you found the answer?

Comment: @parisssss , the guy who answered the [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36058534/how-can-yahoo-mail-be-accessed-by-imap-using-oauth-or-oauth2-authentication) has found that out