# Yahoo OAuth2 have new apps request mail API access

Tags: oauth-2.0, yahoo

Is there any way to create a new Yahoo Oauth2 app with Mail api access? It seems like this feature has been removed and only available to premium accounts.

Going to the 'Create App' link: https://developer.yahoo.com/apps/create/ you can see the Mail access option is no longer available.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can Yahoo Mail be accessed by IMAP using OAuth or OAuth2 authentication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36058534/how-can-yahoo-mail-be-accessed-by-imap-using-oauth-or-oauth2-authentication)