# Where are the Yahoo's current security standards for third party email clients

Tags: android, jakarta-mail, yahoo-mail

What/Where are the current security standards to make an email client that allows yahoo mails to be retrieved without enabling access to less secure apps setting on Yahoo account.

The line below from this [link](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/mail-for-desktop/apps-outdated-security-require-grant-access-yahoo-mail-sln27791.html) says,

Make sure that your third party (non-Yahoo) email programs use current security standards.

But there is no proper documentation where I can refer and start the development of my email client application.

I am looking for some links to documentation or any way to achieve this as I can already see the Google's Gmail app and Bluemail app is able to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

The use of OAuth2 with Yahoo services is described 
[here](https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth2/guide/openid_connect/getting_started.html),
although 
[it's not clear that this still works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36058534/how-can-yahoo-mail-be-accessed-by-imap-using-oauth-or-oauth2-authentication)
since Yahoo will no longer allow you to create an app with Mail permissions.