# Yahoo app connect to mail using oauth

Tags: yahoo-api

[image: API choices]

I want to create a Yahoo app so I can securely connect to email. I know how to do it with Google APIs.

But I am confused with Yahoo. I have not even worked out how to create the app yet but thought I would follow these steps in the image.

It does list simple things like Mail, Calendar.

Confused.

Comment: According to the accepted answer to [How can Yahoo Mail be accessed by IMAP using OAuth or OAuth2 authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36058534/how-can-yahoo-mail-be-accessed-by-imap-using-oauth-or-oauth2-authentication), the mail API access cannot be requested in new apps. I was unsuccessful in my attempt to access Mail.

Comment: @Poosh So if I want to send emails using their smtp server I have no choice but to get them to tick the third party app setting.

Comment: @Poosh What about the last answer on the question you linked to?

Comment: sorry, I have not had luck finding a way to access the mail API through OAuth. Aside from some hacky solutions to get past an OAuth [requiring browser login](https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth2/guide/faq/), I tried searching the Wayback Machine for documentation, and encountered some unreachable endpoints...